# Use makefile to generate version info

Tags: c++, makefile

My app makefile has some version variables and I want my makefile to use that to generate a version.h file. I currently have the common makefile set up like:

```
version :
    @echo "Generating version.h ..."
    @echo line > version.h
    @echo etc >> version.h

debug : blah blah version blah blah
release : blah blah version blah blah

.DEFAULT_GOAL := debug release
```

Where the app-level makefile is:

```
MAJOR_VERSION = 1
MINOR_VERSION = 42

include makefile.common
```

This works, but ends up generating the version file twice. How can I make it only generate once - such that `version` somehow depends on the app-level makefile changing. It's not like generating it twice is unbearably slow, I'd just like to do this right.

Also, I might have an app that doesn't want version info, how do I conditionally generate this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, it is good in general to depend all targets with meaningful recipes, on all included makefiles, since it is hard in general to see which of the makefiles (even included later than the recipe) might contain variables that impact the recipe.

Bearing that in mind, here is the answer to both of your questions (I also added some other "best practices" since you want to learn "the right way"):

Makefile:

```
MAJOR_VERSION := 1
MINOR_VERSION := 42

include makefile.common
```

makefile.common:

```
.PHONY: all debug release
all: debug release

VERSION_FILE := $(if $(filter %OR_VERSION, $(.VARIABLES)), version.h)
debug : blah blah $(VERSION_FILE) blah blah
release : blah blah $(VERSION_FILE) blah blah

.SECONDEXPANSION:
version.h : $$(MAKEFILE_LIST)
    @echo "Generating $@ ..."
    @echo line > $@
    @echo etc >> $@
```

Comment: @Barry so that $$(MAKEFILE_LIST) evaluates not just to the makefiles included at this moment, but _all_ makefiles included, even afterwards.  It is necessary, because some variable values in your recipe may depend on code below it.

Comment: What if I want to filter-out the %.d's? I $(filter-out %.d,$(MAKEFILE_LIST)) works, but I can't figure out a way that works on .SECONDEXPANSION... except just the same again.

Comment: @Barry if you want to do anything with $$, then anything outside of that, also has to have $$, so $$(filter-out %.d,$$(MAKEFILE_LIST)).  Also, in some cases you may need to escape %:  PERCENT=%, then use $$(PERCENT)

Answer (score 1):

You want your make target to be the file, something like:

```
version.h :
    @echo "Generating version.h ..."
    @echo line > version.h
    @echo etc >> version.h

debug : blah blah version.h blah blah
release : blah blah version.h blah blah
```

Comment: If I do this, then if I were to update the makefile to change version variables, version.h wouldn't get rebuilt. Is there a way to enforce that dependency? This is still better than what I have now though.

Comment: To have version.h depend on the version variables, so that it will get rebuilt when they change, you need to express that explicitly in terms of files: 
    "version.h: Makefile"

Answer (score 0):

if you have a version.h file, that contains something like this:

```
#define BUILD_NUMBER "8"
#define BUILD_DATE "2021-08-06"
```

You can add this to the Makefile, somewhere before the compile rules
(SRC_DIRS pointing to where your source file are):

```
AUTOGEN_FILE := $(SRC_DIRS)/version.h
AUTOGEN_NEXT := $(shell expr $$(awk '/#define BUILD_NUMBER/' $(AUTOGEN_FILE) | tr -cd "[0-9]") + 1)
```

The second line, finds "#define BUILD_NUMBER" in version.h file,  extracts it, increments it, and saves it for later.

Then add these two lines to the compile rule (so that you only change the build number, when there is a change):

```
sed -i "s/#define BUILD_NUMBER .*/#define BUILD_NUMBER \"$(AUTOGEN_NEXT)\"/" $(AUTOGEN_FILE)
sed -i "s/#define BUILD_DATE.*/#define BUILD_DATE \"$$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')\"/" $(AUTOGEN_FILE)
```

The first line, finds "#define BUILD_NUMBER..." in version.h and replace it with the new build number.

The second line, finds "#define BUILD_DATE..." and set at new date.

The rule could look like this:

```
# Build step for C source
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c 
    sed -i "s/#define BUILD_NUMBER .*/#define BUILD_NUMBER \"$(AUTOGEN_NEXT)\"/" $(AUTOGEN_FILE)
    sed -i "s/#define BUILD_DATE.*/#define BUILD_DATE \"$$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')\"/" $(AUTOGEN_FILE)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```